# How can i enable/disable the DropDownButton according to the condition in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, dropdownbutton

I am new in flutter and i am making leave application in that I have create two DropdownButton. In that one DropdownButton for **From Date Half Leave:** and Second one for **To Date Half Leave**. I am showing Same Item list in both DropdownButton.
Problem is that when i select same item from the **From Date Half Leave** then it should **do not hide** the same options in second DropdownButton it means in the **To Date Half Leave** .

For example,i want to do that if **From date** and **To date**  Are same then its show option in both dropdownbutton but when user Select the one item from **From Date Half Leave** then it hide the item option in **To Date Half Leave**. and if **From date** and **To date** are different then it show opposite option in **From Date Half Leave** and **To Date Half Leave** like if **From Date Half Leave** select Morning then in **To Date Half Leave** i does not show morning option its show only Afternoon option if the **From Date Half Leave** and **To Date Half Leave** are different then only. **I can't able to do this so help me please..**

My Code Below: i just try to make disable the items of **To Date Half Leave** when the **From Date** and **To Date** are same the when user select **From Date Half Leave** dropdownbutton item the its disable the  items in **To Date Half Leave** .

var _days = ['Morning', 'Afternoon',];

```
    Padding(
                   padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:8.0),
                   child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      //width: 200.0,
                      child: Text('From Date :',
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle2.copyWith(color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                    ),            
                  ]
                ),
              ), 
                 Container(
                       child: Column(
                         children: <Widget>[
                           ListTile(
                            trailing: Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
                            title: Text('$_formdate'),
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left:4.0,right:0.0,),
                            enabled: true,
                            onTap: (){
                             _chooseDate(context);
                             } 
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ), 
                Padding(
                   padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:8.0),
                     child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      child: Text('To Date :',
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle2.copyWith(color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                    ),            
                  ]
                ),
               ), 
               Container(
                       child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                        ListTile(
                        trailing: Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
                        title: Text('$_todate'),
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left:4.0,right:0.0,),
                        enabled: true,
                        onTap: (){
                        _chooseData2(context);
                             } 
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:8.0),
                  child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                    child: Text('From Date Half leave :',
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle2.copyWith(color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                    ),            
                  ]
                ),
             ),   
        new DropdownButton<String>(
            dropdownColor: Colors.grey[300],
            value: currentFDHLvalue,
            isExpanded: true,
            items: _days.map((String value) {
              return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: value,
                child: new Text(value),
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                          underline: Container(
                        height: 1,
                        color: Colors.black26,
            ),
              onChanged: (newValue) {             
              if (_formdate == _todate && currentFDHLvalue != null) {
                setState(() {  });
                             } else{
                               setState((){ 
                                 currentTDHLvalue;
                               disabledItems = false;
                               });
                             }
                         setState(() { 
                            currentFDHLvalue = newValue;
                          }); 
                        },     
          ) ,
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:8.0),
           child: Row(
            hildren: <Widget>[
            Container(
            child: Text('To Date Half leave :',
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle2.copyWith(color: Colors.black),
          ),
        ),            
      ]
    ),
  ),            
        new DropdownButton<String>(
          dropdownColor: Colors.grey[300],
            value: currentTDHLvalue,
            isExpanded: true,
            elevation: 22,
            items: _days.map((String value) {
               return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                value: value,
                 child: new Text(value,
                 style: TextStyle(
                  color: !disabledItems ? Colors.grey : null,
            )
          ),
        );
      }).toList(),
        underline: Container(
         height: 1,
         color: Colors.black26,
            ),
      onChanged: (newValue) {
              if (!disabledItems ? _formdate != _todate : currentTDHLvalue != newValue ) {
                setState(() {
                  currentTDHLvalue = newValue;
                  disabledItems = false;
                });
              }
            setState(() {
              currentTDHLvalue = newValue;
              });   
        },
) ,
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hx9C.png)

Comment: you can have this logic you know. If I select afternoon then I remove the morning from the  next list directly and vice versa. So if I change it back to morning it removes morning and add afternoon. Complicated but can be done.